# How to implement Django 'UserCreationForm' to check users from an existing mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am beginning a Django app using UserCreationForm, the default´s Django app for users. It creates a table in mysql and then you are able to create new users. But what I need is to compare the users with an existing database in MySQL. How can I specify the database in wich the UserCreationForm has to look for the users?
My view for the main with the fields to fill login:

```
def mainview(request):
    if not request.user.is_anonymous():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/private')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid:
            usuario = request.POST['username']
            clave = request.POST['password']

            acceso = authenticate(username=usuario, password=clave)
            if acceso is not None:
                if acceso.is_active:
                    login(request, acceso)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/privado')
                else:
                    return render_to_response('noactivo.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                return render_to_response('nousuario.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        formulario = AuthenticationForm()
    return render_to_response('mainview.html',{'formulario':formulario}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

Comment: the problem is that when you configure a database like this django creates his own tables. I need to look for users in a different and existing database that is shared by a mobile app also.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this, create an own User model and make username unique, but the easiest way; inherit `UserCreationForm` and add a `clean_username` function.

So something like:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exists")
        # return is not required Django 1.7 and up, but do it anyway
        return username
```

==== Update after comment ====
There are two databases, so you need to add the second database within your settings (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases).
Lets say you name the second database 'usernames'. Now there again two options. First option is, doing raw SQL with a cursor (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['usernames'].cursor()
```

Second option is create a Model which has the same design as your current table. Use the above form, but use `using` on the queryset. So something like this:

```
if YourModel.objects.using('usernames').filter(username=username).exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exists")
```

Comment: Thanks, im going to try this option

Comment: But my problem is still the same. I want to look for the username in a different and existing MySQL table, not the one that Django creates.

Comment: Oké, I will adjust my answer

Comment: Updated the answer, the first new option would probally be the best.

Comment: Thank you, i am going to try with a cursor, i didnt know this before.